# loader prop in react-router-dom typescript error for params prop type definition

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom, react-typescript

i was trying to using params prop in the loader prop in the routes, since i am using typescript i define the params as shown below but typescript is yelling at me i do not know why?
please any way i can get around this would be apperciated, thanks in advance.

```
Type '({ params }: CustomLoaderFunctionArgs) => Promise<any>' is not assignable to type 'LoaderFunction<any>'.
  Type '({ params }: CustomLoaderFunctionArgs) => Promise<any>' is not assignable to type '(args: LoaderFunctionArgs<any>) => DataFunctionValue | Promise<DataFunctionValue>'.
    Types of parameters '__0' and 'args' are incompatible.
      Type 'LoaderFunctionArgs<any>' is not assignable to type 'CustomLoaderFunctionArgs'.
        Type 'LoaderFunctionArgs<any>' is not assignable to type '{ params: { id: string; }; }'.
          Types of property 'params' are incompatible.
            Property 'id' is missing in type 'Params<string>' but required in type '{ id: string; }'.ts(2322)
patient-form.tsx(45, 66): 'id' is declared here.
components.d.ts(61, 5): The expected type comes from property 'loader' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RouteProps'
(property) loader: ({ params }: CustomLoaderFunctionArgs) => Promise<any>
No quick fixes available
```

```
function App() {
  const router = createBrowserRouter(
    createRoutesFromElements(
      <Route path="/" element={<RootLayout />}>
        <Route index element={<IndexPage />} />
        <Route path="about" element={<ContactPage />} />
        <Route path="sign-in" element={<SignInPage />} />
        <Route path="sign-up" element={<SignUpPage />} />
        <Route path="dashboard" element={<DashboardLayout />}>
          <Route index element={<DashboardPage />} loader={patientsDataLoader} />
          <Route path="patient/:id" element={<PatientForm initialData={null} />} loader={patientDataLoader}/>
        </Route>
      </Route>
    )
  );

  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}

export default App;
```

```
export const patientDataLoader = async ({params} : {params: {id: string}}) => {
  const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/patient/${params.id}`);
  return response.data;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the way you passed the params to the function. In the documentation, it's mentioned how to pass params to the loader function. Please check it out and check the following solution.

```
createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/teams/:teamId",
    loader: ({ params }) => {
      return fakeGetTeam(params.teamId);
    },
  },
]);
```

For your function:

```
export const patientDataLoader = async ({ params }) => {
  const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/patient/${params.id}`);
  return response.data;
}
```

Document link: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/loader

Comment: it seems if i need to access the params i can n't use it other place like i did.

Comment: Yes, @ayex. loader property expecting params in that format.

Answer (score 2):

React-Router basically already types the [params](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/9f36087045fd8577ed1aa23f119e5b9e83933ab4/packages/router/utils.ts#L369C1-L374C3) object and the values are effectively always optional.

> ```
> /**
>  * The parameters that were parsed from the URL path.
>  */
> export type Params<Key extends string = string> = {
>   readonly [key in Key]: string | undefined;
> };
> ```

> ```
> /**
>  * @private
>  * Arguments passed to route loader/action functions.  Same for now but we keep
>  * this as a private implementation detail in case they diverge in the future.
>  */
> interface DataFunctionArgs<Context> {
>   request: Request;
>   params: Params;
>   context?: Context;
> }
> ```

> ```
> /**
>  * Arguments passed to loader functions
>  */
> export interface LoaderFunctionArgs<Context = any>
>   extends DataFunctionArgs<Context> {}
> ```

It is common practice to cast `params` to the type that includes the specific path parameters.

Example:

```js
export const patientDataLoader = async ({ params }) => {
  const { id } = params as { id: string };

  const { data } = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/patient/${id}`);
  return data;
}
```